# Switching the body of scaffold dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have application which has one `scaffold` and `BottomNavigationBar` inside.

Now I want to change the `body` of `scaffold` according to tapping.

At first I think I should use variable to stock BodyLayout || CatListLayout.

However it doesn't work. How should I do??

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

    body: BodyLayout(articles),  // it works
  //body: CatListLayout(cats), // and it al so works

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('article'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('cat'),
        ),
      ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
}

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (index == 0){
     // want to change body to BodyLayout
    }
    if ( index == 1){
     // want to change body to CatListLayout
    }

}  
class BodyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
        /////
        );
    }
}
class CatListLayout extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
        ////
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `body: index == 0? BodyLayout(articles) : CatListLayout(cats)` and inside `_onItemTapped` you should call `setState` to rebuild your widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is this, but then you dont have any backbutton control cause you are not using a Navigator. Just keep this in mind. Using a Navigator for these kind of subpages inside a body is a bit more tricky than using different scaffolds.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  int myIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: myIndex == 0 ? BodyLayout(articles) : CatListLayout(cats), 
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('article'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('cat'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      setState(() {
        myIndex = 0;
      });
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      setState(() {
        myIndex = 1;
      });
    }
  }
}

class BodyLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        /////
        );
  }
}

class CatListLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        ////
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will check about the relationship between scaffold and  ListView.

Answer (score 2):

So there are several ways to do this. You can use the PageView widget and control its controller when you click on the button. Another option is to store the index of the current page for this the whole page widget should be stateful. After clicking on the button, you change this index and call setState to rebuild the widget. When building a widget, you look at the current index and display the content associated with this index